# How to add items to a dictionary that contains a dictionary within

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add items to a dictionary that contains a dictionary within please refer the code below.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
foreach (var item in TrainingCourseList)
{
    // I have to add item.ID,item.Name,item.Score something like below
    dict.Add(item.ID,item.Name,item.Score);
}
```

Comment: How do you refer to the outer dictionary item?

Comment: The types of the dictionary don't befit the data. Is this "dictionary" declaration set in stone or can you modify it? I would expect something like Dictionary<Item>. Right now, it's as if one unique item (IDs are unique right?) have _multiple_ names and scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `Tuple<string, string, int>` is the best suit for your case, not Dictionary:

```
var list = TrainingCourseList
    .Select(item => Tuple.Create(item.ID, item.Name, item.Score));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add an entry to the outer dictionary you have to do something like

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
    foreach (var item in TrainingCourseList)
    {
        // i have to add item.ID,item.Name,item.Score something like below
        dict.Add(item.ID,new Dictionary<string,int>{{item.Name,item.Score}};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
foreach (var item in TrainingCourseList)
{
    // i have to add item.ID,item.Name,item.Score something like below
    dict.Add(item.ID, new Dictionary<string, int> { item.Name, item.Score });
}
```